# Vertical scroll bar of Qtreeview is not proportional to the size of the content

Tags: treeview, qwidget, qtreeview

When you tested Qtreeview in the application below, the vertical scrollbar normally works proportional to the content.

````
class MyTreeView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        # Add some example items to the model
        numofItems = 30
        for x in range(numofItems):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem('Test {}'.format(x+1))
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            model.appendRow(item)
        # Create the QTreeView
        treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        treeView.setModel(model)
        
        # QTreeView vertical scrollbar configuration
        v_scrollbar = treeView.verticalScrollBar()
        v_scrollbar.setMinimumWidth(15)  
        v_scrollbar.setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:vertical { width: 15px; }")
        # Main layout
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(treeView)
        self.setLayout(lay)```
  

When I use the same Qtreeview in an application that uses a QMainwindow, within a Qdock the vertical scrollbar becomes small.
````

Comment: The final part of the code- `app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
  window = MyTreeView()
  window.show()
  app.exec_()`